# Community-proposed tag icons

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I think everybody knows about the (sponsored) tag icons we have here on Stack Overflow:

[image: Angular]
[image: SQL Server]
[image: Android]

Would it be possible to have a process where the users of Stack Overflow could propose tag icons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The icons are actually a part of our [Tag Sponsorship](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising/solutions/tag-sponsorship) advertising package, which is a paid product. We do not simply add icons to tags for the sake of having icons.

Comment: What about tags that nobody can/would advertise on, such as, for example, [tag:c]? We could add a K&R logo on there or something.

Comment: We don't have any interest in maintaining icons for tags that cannot be claimed by a specific company. The icons are meant to symbolize a company's involvement and/or recognition of the community behind the tag. Trying to force logos into every tag is distracting and unnecessary, which is why it's always been reserved for a specific purpose.